# Error 1064 while running PASSWORD function in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, change-password

I've been busting my ass from last two days to update authentication_string of my root user and mysql is throwing ERROR 1064 at my face. I've tried every option I could (of course except the correct one which I don't know XD. After logging in as ROOT, I tried this code.

```
mysql> UPDATE MYSQL.USER SET AUTHENTICATION_STRING = PASSWORD('OJ') WHERE `USER` = 'ROOT';
```

And I'm getting following error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('OJ') WHERE `USER` = 'ROOT'' at line 1
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong here.
Thank you.

Comment: [This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)

Comment: Thank you. Solved it by downgrading my MySQL version.